# Converting a Static Bootstrap website to Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, less

I have a bootstrap website that's setup statically, it doesn't adjust according to different view sizes. So I would like to make it responsive but not sure how. I'm also using LESS to do my modifications and such to the twitter bootstrap css. So far my site is set up like so..

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <header>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
               <!-- LOGO HERE -->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </header>
   <div id="main-content" class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="span8">
            <!-- My content -->
         </div>
         <div class="span4">
            <!-- My content too -->
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also, the website was built for 940px so when I make it responsive I want to set the maximum veiw of the page to 940px instead of 1200px and have my div.wrapper still in the center of the page.

Hopefully all this makes sence haha.

Comment: just download the Bootstrap from http://www.initializr.com/, and you're responsive already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn on responsive layout, you need to add the following code in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You'll have to adjust your reference to the stylesheet to your specific structure, since you're using the .less source.

In responsive.less comment out or delete the following line:

```
@import "responsive-1200px-min.less";
```

This will respond to smaller screen resolutions, but keep your maximum .container width at 940px.

Answer (score 1):

Change `.container` to `.container-fluid` and `.row` to `.row-fluid`. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/ypkJQ/. You have to also remember that every .row-fluid class resets span*  width counter, that is span* width under .row-fluid is taken from percentage width of parent(.row-fluid).

Comment: Alright thanks a lot! Now if I want to change the maximum size of my layout do I remove @import "responsive-1200px-min.less" from the responsive.less file (i just read that in a different post)?  Because everything is stretching the entire width of my screen now and its covering up my background picture/colors.